# Two tags as one paragraph

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx

I have a requirement to put two  tags in same line/ same paragraph

```
<h3>This is first paragraph. </h3>
<h3>This is second paragraph.</h3>
```

I want output like below

```
This is first paragraph. This is
Second paragraph
```

Basically, The second tag is just a continuation to first one. when my width is done, It should fall under second line and start at beginning like above

I saw few examples in stack overflow like below

```
This is first paragraph.  This is Second 
                          paragraph.
```

They are using flex box or align:left and right, I don't want this. I want all tags as single paragraph

Comment: "display: inline"? Or just make them one tag?

Comment: Check out my answer, it should help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: inline` to both of them like:

```
<h3 style="display: inline">This is first paragraph.</h3>
<h3 style="display: inline">This is second paragraph.</h3>
```

You can do it in css file with classes of course. This is a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Headings are block style elements, so putting two block level elements one after another are going to be styled that way. You need to use `display: inline` on your styles for this text.

That being said, I think having multiple headings directly following each other as separate elements isn't a great web accessibility practice. Is there a reason you can't just have this be one heading element?